# Free PHP-based helpdesk chat software

Tags: php, chat, help-desk

We have a helpdesk which at the moment accepts only phone calls and emails, which is a little problematic when we need to request a lot of technical information step by step. We have a lot of systems which log everything, and do not want an all in one solution.

We need a simple, highly customizable chat which we can integrate with all of our systems, aka code which is easy to read/modify. I am developing everything in PHP, and would like a solution which uses PHP and MySql. I have looked at PHP Live!, which does everything that we want it to do, but it is not free.

Does anyone know software which will do this, but without a price tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveHelperChat might be exactly what your looking for,

**[LiveHelperChat](https://livehelperchat.com/)** ([OpenSource](https://github.com/LiveHelperChat/livehelperchat))

> Open source - Live Support chat for your website. Web and desktop clients. Co-Browsing, XMPP notifications, GTalk, Jabber, Openfire, Skype, Chrome extension, Node.js support, MySQL, PostgreSQL
>
> [image: LiveHelperChat Guest Side]
>
> [image: LiveHelperChat Admin Panel]

The code for LiveHelperChat can be found [Here](https://github.com/LiveHelperChat/livehelperchat), it shouldn't be too hard to learn how it works and start customizing it the way you like.

Comment: wow... That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great, happy to help:)